# How do I give proper attribution when distributing my modified Ambiance theme?

Tags: themes, legal

I made a modified version of 12.04's Ambiance that uses a dark sidebar for Nautilus, and I would like to redistribute it via e.g. [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/).

From the [Launchpad page for the `light-themes` package](https://launchpad.net/light-themes), it says the themes are available under a Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 license. The way I understand it, I can distribute my modified theme so long as I provide proper attribution for it and place it under the same license.

In this case, who do I attribute as the author of the original theme and where/how should I display this attribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the `light-themes` scheme, you need to include a file called copyright (or LICENSE) in `/usr/share/doc/your-theme-name` that includes the complete `/usr/share/doc/light-themes/copyright` file), which starts as:

```
Upstream Author: Kenneth Wimer 

Copyright: (c) Canonical Ltd 2004- 2010

Unless otherwise indicated, artwork is available under the Creative
Commons Attribution Share-alike license v3.0 or any later version. To
view a copy of this license, visit
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ or send a letter to
Creative Commons, 171 Second Street, Suite 300, San Francisco,
California, 94105, USA. See below for the full text of the license.

Some Rights Reserved: 

The rights in the trademarks, logos, service marks of Canonical Ltd,
as well as the look and feel of Ubuntu, are not licensed under the
Creative Commons license and are subject to the Canonical Trademark
Policy at http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/TrademarkPolicy

License: 
full CC license (see the `copyright` file)
```

- At the beginning, include a line like `Derived from the Ubuntu light-themes package`.
- After the "Upstream Author", as a courtesy I would also add `Maintainers:` and include the [Ubuntu Light Themes Contributors](https://launchpad.net/~light-themes-contributors),  preferably with the link to their page.

---

If you are simply distributing this as a zip file or a patch or something, just including all the above as a `LICENSE` file in the root or inline as a comment (in that case no need for the full license text, just link http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ ).